# Got an error while installing react router can anyone solve my problem?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-router

I have this error

```
D:\>npm install react-router-dom
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path D:\
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'D:\'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: 'D:\\'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\my-app\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-07T07_21_15_220Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: What command are you running to produce this error? Just `npm install react-router-dom`? What version of `node` and `npm` are you using? See [mcve]. I think you should also be doing this from a project directory and not the root of your `D:` drive.

Comment: Yes, I used "npm install react-router-dom" I am using the latest version of node and npm. Yes, it is a project drive I did not wanted to mix it with the C: drive.

Comment: Well, I meant that you want to be installing the dependencies into an *actual* project directory, i.e. `D:\projects\my-project`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a permission Issue.
You're running this command as a non-administrator user.
Open **cmd** as an administrator
and run this command,
It will work

Comment: No, I first thought it was that error, but it wasn't. I than opened it with the administrator and got the same error.